# How meteor works without directory structure?

Tags: meteor

I am a newbie to meteor. I wonder how meteor works without directory structure. Usually web server runs `index` file in default, and MVC frameworks have route, controllers, model and view in a specific directory structure with file naming. I understand somehow meteor identifies Client code by `Meteor.isClient` and Server code by `Meteor.isServer`. I want to know how it identifies default `index` file? And explain me how the structure works?

Answer (score 1):

There is no index. From the [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/livehtmltemplates):

> When your app is loaded, it automatically renders the special template
>   called <body>, which is written using the  element instead of a
>   . You insert a template inside another template by using the
>   {{> inclusion}} operator.

```
<!-- in myapp.html -->
<body>
  <h1>Today's weather!</h1>
  {{> forecast}}
</body>
```

So put your  tags in any html file and it will find them. I usually put them in a file called body.html so I know where they are.

As far as structuring your app, again from the [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp)

You don't always have to use `Meteor.isClient`. There are some special folders in Meteor. Two of them are *client* and *server*. Putting code in these folders will load that code only in the client or only in the server. There are more special names explained in the documentation.